# Splitting a byte[] into multiple byte[] arrays

Tags: android

I am trying to "chunk" up the bytes of an image. This will allow me to upload a large image in bytes array. I have the image currently stored as one large byte[]. I would like to split the byte array into byte[]'s with a each exactly of 5 MB.

Comment: And what have you tried ?

Comment: `I am trying to "chunk" up the bytes of an image. This will allow me to upload a large image in portions.` That is a very bad idea. And not needed at all. You can just upload a 'portion' of a byte array in a write() using offset and length parameter. `write(buffer, offset, length);`.

Comment: Portions? For what? Every day one until done? I do not see an advantage.

Comment: if your data chunk comes some from file its better to read file as stream until it reaches to some limit like 1024 bytes and sending it to server than resuming reading stream until all bytes sent to server

Comment: @greenapps I agree with you that there are better ways, like streaming, but chunking it up will allow you to simply do partial uploads. If you lose connection after say 500mb for a file of 505mb, you don't need to start all over uploading. This is useful for slow connections or unstable connections such as mobile.

Comment: If you just put the whole file in memory again then divide it in parts after loosing a connection then parting makes no sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
public static byte[][] divideArray(byte[] source, int chunksize) {


        byte[][] ret = new byte[(int) Math.ceil(source.length / (double) chunksize)][chunksize];

        int start = 0;

        int parts = 0;


        for (int i = 0; i < ret.length; i++) {
            if (start + chunksize > source.length) {
                System.arraycopy(source, start, ret[i], 0, source.length - start);
            } else {
                System.arraycopy(source, start, ret[i], 0, chunksize);
            }
            start += chunksize;
            parts++;
        }

        Log.d("Parts", parts + "");

        return ret;
    }
```

Call It by

```
divideArray(common.fullyReadFileToBytes(wallpaperDirectory), 5 * 1024 * 1024)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [copyOfRange](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange(T[],%20int,%20int)) for that:

```
T[] copyOfRange (T[] original, 
            int from, 
            int to);
```

In your case, something like this:

```
Byte[] copyOfRange (original, 
            0, 
            5000000);
```

make sure you calculate the offset:

```
class test {

  // this is just for dummy data
  public static byte[] getTestBytes() {
    byte[] largeByteArray = new byte[50_000_000];
    for(int i = 0; i < 50_000_000; i ++) {
      largeByteArray[i] = 0;
    }
    return largeByteArray;
  }


  // this method splits your byte array into small portions 
  // and returns a list with those portions
  public static List<byte[]> byteToPortions(byte[] largeByteArray) {
    // create a list to keep the portions
    List<byte[]> byteArrayPortions = new ArrayList<>();

    // 5mb is about 5.000.000 bytes
    int sizePerPortion = 5_000_000;
    int offset = 0;

    // split the array
    while(offset < largeByteArray.length) {
      // into 5 mb portions
      byte[] portion = Arrays.copyOfRange(largeByteArray, offset, offset + sizePerPortion);

      // update the offset to increment the copied area
      offset += sizePerPortion;

      // add the byte array portions to the list
      byteArrayPortions.add(portion);
    }

    // return portions
    return byteArrayPortions;
  }

  // create your byte array, and split it to portions
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    byte[] largeByteArray = getTestBytes();

    List<byte[]> portions = byteToPortions(largeByteArray);

    // work with your portions
  }
}
```

---

Something cool: the value `to` does **not** have to be an index inside the array, it checks that for you without erroring and copies a subset that is valid to the intended array.

Comment: i want to divide byte array into multiple byte array with each of size with 5Mb in how can i do this ?

Comment: @VishalPatoliyaツ See the updated answer for a working example. The `main method` uses the functions, so start reading there.

Answer (score 0):

These answers work fine but has optimization issues. They allocate extra space of the whole chunk size irrespective of the only actual bytes of memory the array needs to allocate for copying the data.
Here is the solution for this problem.

```
private fun divideDataIntoChunks(source: ByteArray, chunkSize: Int): kotlin.collections.ArrayList<ByteArray> {
        val result: ArrayList<ByteArray> = ArrayList()
        if (chunkSize <= 0) {
            result.add(source)
        } else {
            for (chunk in source.indices step chunkSize) {
                result.add(source.copyOfRange(chunk, min(chunk+chunkSize,source.size)))
            }
        }
        return result
    }
```